# how do duckduckgo spice IA secondary API calls get their parameters?

Tags: perl, duckduckgo

I have been looking through the spice instant answer [source code](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-spice). Yes, I know it is in [maintenance mode](https://duckduckhack.com/), but I am still curious.

The [documentation](https://github.com/duckduckgo/duckduckhack-docs/blob/master/walkthroughs/forum-lookup.md) makes it fairly clear that the primary `spice to` API gets its numerical parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc. from the `handle` function.

My question: should there be secondary API calls included with `spice alt_to` as, say, in the [movie spice IA](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-spice/blob/master/lib/DDG/Spice/Movie.pm), where do the numerical parameters to *that* API call come from?

Note, for instance, the `$1` in both the `movie_image` and `cast_image` secondary API calls in `spice alt_to` at the preceding link. I am asking which regex capture returns those instances of `$1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I see how this works now. The flow of information is still a bit murky to me, but at least I see how all of the requisite information is there.

I'll take the [cryptocurrency](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-spice/blob/master/lib/DDG/Spice/Cryptocurrency.pm) instant answer as an example. The `alt_to` element in the perl package file at that link has a key named `cryptonator`. The [corresponding `.js` file](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-spice/blob/master/share/spice/cryptocurrency/cryptocurrency.js) constructs a matching endpoint:

```
var endpoint = "/js/spice/cryptonator/" + from + "/" + to;
```

Note the general shape of the "remainder" past `/js/spice/cryptonator`: `from/to`, where `from` and `to` will be two strings.

Back in the [perl package](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-spice/blob/master/lib/DDG/Spice/Cryptocurrency.pm) the hash `alt_to->{cryptonator}` has a key `from` which receives, I think, this remainder `from/to`. The value corresponding to that key is a regex meant to split up that string into its two constituents:

```
from => '([^/]+)/([^/]*)'
```

Applied to `from/to`, that regex will return `$1=from` and `$2=to`. *These*, then, are the `$1` and `$2` that go into

```
to => 'https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/$1-$2'
```

in `alt_to`.

---

In short:

The `to` field of `alt_to->{blah}` receives its numerical parameters by having the `from` regex operate on the remainder past `/js/spice/blah/` of the name of the corresponding endpoint constructed in the relevant `.js` file.